# for loop in return statement

Tags: python, for-loop, return

I have a problem with this piece of code:

```
List=[' ', 'X', 'X', 'X']+[' ']*6
le='X'
def Return():
    return((for i in range(1, 10, 3):
        (List[i]==le and List[i+1]==le and List[i+2]==le)))
```

I wanted to write it with a for-loop instead of having to specify like this:

```
 def Return():
    return ((List[1]==le and List[2]==le and List[3]==le) or #True
        (List[4]==le and List[5]==le)...etc.)
```

When I use the foor-loop I just get a message saying "invalid syntax", but I don't get why.

Answer (score 2):

You could use what is called ["List comprehensions"](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def Return():
    return any([List[i]==le and List[i+1]==le and List[i+2]==le for i in range(1, 10, 3)])
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks right! I just have one problem still, when I want to check if the Return() function returns "True" (which it should right?), I tried typing: if Return==True: Print('true'). But the program doesn't print anything.

Comment: it should be any . since OP is trying for or condition

Comment: @user3815466: You need to be trying `if Return() == True: print('true')`. Note the case of `print` and the parenthesis to actually call return. Otherwise you are comparing a function with a truth value...

Comment: @Antoine: If I'm not wrong, this isn't a generator expression per se. It's just a list comprehension. You need to remove the square brackets `[]` to make it a generator expression. Also, as @sundar notes, it should be `any`.

Comment: @Praveen: Yes you are right. I will correct my answer.

Comment: You could also do `List[i:i+3] == [le,le,le]` (I know this will create lots of temporary lists, but this should not be much of a problem)

Comment: Haha thank you so much for your help, It works perfectly with all the suggestions! :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because `for` in Python isn't an expression, it has no value that you can `return`.

Comment: Oh, ok! Thanks for explaining that. Is there some other way the latter code could be simplified then? It feels kinda tedious to print every single number down if it would be a longer list

Answer (score 1):

you can try using `any`

```
lis=[' ', 'X', 'X', 'X']+[' ']*6
le='X'
def func():
    return any(all(lis[j]==le for j in range(i,i+3)) for i in range(0,len(lis),3)
```

Note: Never use the python keywords as method names and variables

Comment: Ok I'll definetly keep that in mind! I don't see how your code would take three numbers at a time though, it rather returns true if only any number==le. But maybe it is me who's stupid :P